# re.search error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-re

I am creating a python program that guesses a person's desired word like Hangman. However, when I was using regex in this function, it TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. Whole code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = load_words()
    length=get_length()
    seq="."*length
    guessed=[]
    while True:
        print_word=seq.replace(".","_")
        print_word=print_word[:-1]
        print(print_word)
        words = find_all_words(words,seq)
        letter=find_letter(words,seq,guessed)
        guessed.append(letter)
        seq = response(letter,seq)


import re as regex

def load_words():
    with open('words_alpha.txt') as word_file:
        valid_words = set(word_file.read().split())

    return valid_words


def check_longest(words):
    longest: int = 0
    for word in words:
        length = len(word)
        if length > longest:
            longest = length
    return longest

def find_all_words(words, sequence):
    all_words = []
    for word in words:
        match = regex.search(sequence,word)
        if match:
            all_words.append(word)
    return all_words

def find_letter(words,sequence,guessed):
    letters=dict({})
    seq="^"+sequence
    for word in words:
        print(word)
        print(type(word))
        in_criteria = regex.search(seq,words)
        print(in_criteria)
        if in_criteria:
            for letter in word:
                if letter not in guessed:
                    if letter not in letters:
                        letters[letter]=1
                    else:
                        letters[letter]+=1
    return max(letters.values())



def get_length():
    while True:
        try:
            length = int(input("What's the length of your word?"))
            confirm = input(f"Your word will be {length} words long. Press enter to confirm. " +
                            "If not, type the word length.")
            if confirm:
                length = int(confirm)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a number. Try again.")
    return length


def response(letter, sequence):
    while True:
        res = input(f"My guess is {letter}. If your word contains that letter, type the spaces that contain it below." +
                    " For example, if your word is 'alias' and I guess 'i', you should respond [3]. " +
                    " Or, if I guessed 'a', you should respond [1,4]." +
                    " Or, if I guessed 'e', just press Enter.")
        if res:
            try:
                for hit in res:
                    if sequence[hit] - 1 != ".":
                        sequence[hit] = letter
                        break
                    else:
                        print("That space(s) already have letters. Try again.")
            except TypeError:
                print("Invalid syntax.")
        return sequence
```

The whole traceback: (Includes the `input()`s.)

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/scythia/Desktop/hangman/index.py
What's the length of your word? *3*
Your word will be 3 words long. Press enter to confirm. If not, type the word length.
__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/hangman/index.py", line 15, in <module>
    letter=find_letter(words,seq,guessed)
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/hangman/words.py", line 32, in find_letter
    in_criteria = regex.search(seq,words)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
cytoarchitecture
<class 'str'>  <--This shows that the word is indeed a string.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was using the word library from here: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Comment: According to the stack trace - check line 32 in function `find_letter`. [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) takes pattern and string. Your arguments are `seq`, and `words`. Do you mean to pass in `word`? It's complaining because `words` is a set of strings.

Comment: oh, yeah. Sorry :(